# django ImportError: cannot import name 'connections'

Tags: python, django

I get this error:

```
from django.conf import connections
ImportError: cannot import name 'connections'
```

In my code `helpers\result_set_helper.py`:

```
from django.conf import connections

def fetch_filter_rule_sql_from_ui_db(filter_rule_id):
    with connections['frontend'].cursor() as cursor:
        query = "SELECT id, name FROM dmf_filter_rules"
        cursor.execute(query)
        return dictfetchall(cursor)
```

Folder Structure:

```
root_project_folder:
  - main_project
    - settings.py
  - helpers
    - result_set_helper.py
  - app1
```

Comment: This issue can be because of the project structure, please share the same.

Comment: @manpreetSingh I have added a project structure, and that should give the idea.

Comment: @Azima you might did the wrong import here

Comment: it should be "connection" instead of "connections", @SahilDesai is correct.

Comment: @manpreetSingh connection, connections both can be used. connections is used when you want to fetch dictionary like object. You can follow the link more details are given

Comment: @SahilDesai 's answer solved it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from django.db import connections
```

there is no connections function in django.conf

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/sql/